# Configure vhost file with apache

Tags: php, apache

When I configure vhost usually I do:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
```

Is it possible not to type the port? Like

```
<VirtualHost *:*>
```

?

I tried it and it does not work!

Thank you so much!

Comment: Did you try? what happened?

Comment: try `<VirtualHost *>`

Comment: Nothing happens, the first virtualhost gets the default. Only one * did not work as well as bansi sugested.